# How to change the Point coordinates of opengl in the center

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I'm working with `QT`  , I will to design a point (0,0) with OPENGL . 
the problem is : the point Not in the middle  :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/diB33.png

my code :

the header :

```
#ifndef BRM_H
#define BRM_H

#include <QGLWidget>

#include<qwidget.h>
class brm : public QGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    int x , y ;
    explicit brm(QWidget *parent = 0);

    void initializeGL();
    void paintGL();
    void resize(int a ,int b);


};

#endif // BRM_H
```

the class :

```
#include<brm.h>
#include<qgl.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
brm::brm(QWidget *parent )
    : QGLWidget( parent)
{


}




void
brm::initializeGL(){
    glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
}

void brm::paintGL(){



    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);



    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2f(0.0, 0.0);
    glEnd();
}

void brm::resize(int a , int b){

}
```

I will change the point , in the middle like this : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRC2e.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
void brm::resize(int a , int b){
    glViewport(-a/2, -b/2, a, b);
}
```

After that, the [0, 0] position should be always at the center of the widget.

Comment: It remained the same problem

Answer (score 1):

why not define 2 more variables that (if you add these two with your point coordinates, you have your corrected coordinates)
so

```
const int MIDLLE_X = 1280 / 2; //or whatever your width divided by 2 is
const int MIDDLE_Y = 720 / 2; //or whatever your height divided by 2 is
```

(make them global if possible)

so (MIDDLE_X, MIDDLE_Y) as a coordinate is in the center

than you can make 2 function

```
int centerizeX(int x) { // wants the X coordinate
       return x + MIDDLE_X;
}

int centerizeY(int y) { // wants the Y coordinate
       return y + MIDDLE_X;
}
```

with that you can still work with your coordinates, they can even go negative. But when you want to render, draw (whatever that has to do with screen) than you should call these 2 functions to, well correct their appereance positions.

Comment: It remained the same problem